# How can I apply changes for the speed variable also in the Update at run time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's working fine in the Start :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Objects To Move")]
    public Transform objectToMovePrefab;
    public int numberOfObjectsToMove = 1;

    [Header("Delay At Start")]
    public bool useDelay = false;
    public bool randomDelayTime = false;
    public float delayTime = 3f;

    [Header("Movement Speed")]
    public float speed = 3f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    //with this approach, you use GameObjects to represent your waypoints 
    //(they can be empty if you want the waypoint to be invisible)
    [Header("Waypoints")]
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> waypoints;
    private List<WaypointsFollower> waypointsFollowers;

    [Header("LineRenderer")]
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private bool useLineRenderer = true;
    private List<Vector3> lineRendererPositions;
    [SerializeField] int lineRendererNumOfPositions;

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToMove; i++)
        {
            var parent = GameObject.Find("Moving Object Parent");
            var objectToMove = Instantiate(objectToMovePrefab, parent.transform);
            objectToMove.name = "Platfrom";
        }

        foreach (GameObject mn in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Moving Object"))
        {
            waypointsFollowers.Add(mn.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>());
        }

            StartCoroutine(SendObjectToMove());
    }

    public int Count => lineRendererPositions.Count;
    public Vector3 GetWaypoint(int index)
    {
        return lineRendererPositions[index];
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (useLineRenderer && lineRenderer.positionCount > 0 && CurvedLineRenderer.linesSet)
        {
            lineRendererPositions = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
            lineRendererNumOfPositions = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace().Count;

            foreach(Transform waypoint in waypoints)
            {
                lineRendererPositions.Add(waypoint.position);
            }

            useLineRenderer = false;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator SendObjectToMove()
    {
        foreach (GameObject mn in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Moving Object"))
        {
            WaypointsFollower waypointsFollower =  mn.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>();

            if (useDelay)
            {
                if (randomDelayTime)
                {
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1, 5));
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
                }
            }

            if (randomSpeed)
            {
                waypointsFollower.speed = Random.Range(1, 100);
            }
            else
            {
                waypointsFollower.speed = speed;
            }

            if (waypoints.Count > 0 || lineRendererPositions.Count > 0)
            {
                waypointsFollower.go = true;
            }
            else
            {
                waypointsFollower.go = false;
            }
        }
    }

    List<Vector3> GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        var pointsToMove = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(pointsToMove);

        //the points returned are in world space
        return pointsToMove.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then on each moving object cloned prefab I added this script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointsFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Waypoints waypoints;
    public float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float waypointDistanceThreshold = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private bool goBack = false;
    public bool go = false;

    private int waypointIndex = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.Find("Waypoints").GetComponent<Waypoints>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (go && waypoints.Count > 0)
        {
            Vector3 waypoint = waypoints.GetWaypoint(waypointIndex);
            //movement
            float distance = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoint, distance);

            //check if we've reached the waypoint
            float threshold = waypointDistanceThreshold; //how close is considered having reached the waypoint
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoint) < threshold)
            {
                //wraps back to 0 when we reach last waypoint
                if (goBack)
                {
                    waypointIndex = (waypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Count;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (waypointIndex != waypoints.Count - 1)
                        waypointIndex = waypointIndex + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can control the speed of each Follower individual but I also want to control the speed of all the Followers from the main Waypoints script and for now I can change the speed in the Inspector and it will affect the changes only in the Start() when starting the game.

How can I make that it will change the speed of all the Followers also in the Update at run time ?

I created a List of all the Followers :

```
foreach (GameObject mn in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Moving Object"))
            {
                waypointsFollowers.Add(mn.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>());
            }
```

but not sure how to apply the speed changes in the Update ? Looping in the Update over the Followers each frame is too expensive I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you would like to achieve. Well, I know you want to increase the variable `Speed` on a list of objects that have the component `WaypointsFollower()`. I suppose what I am confused about is when you want to do this. If `Update()` is too frequent, what determines when the speed should change?

In your original code, you are using the `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Moving Object"))` too frequently. Only do this once in `Awake()` or `Start()`. If any new objects are instantiated, then dynamically add them to the list. Using the `FindGameObjectsWithTag` frequently can get very expensive. What I am referring to is that you are already storing them, but then in the method `SendObjectToMove()` you are using it again. Is there a reason you need to call it again in that IEnumartor?

And if you are instantiating these objects on this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToMove; i++)
{
    var parent = GameObject.Find("Moving Object Parent");
    var objectToMove = Instantiate(objectToMovePrefab, parent.transform);
    objectToMove.name = "Platfrom";
}
```

Then just store the reference after instantiating them instead of using the `FindGameObjectsWithTag`.

Here is a very condensed version of your code.

```
private List<WaypointsFollower> waypointsFollowers;

private void Start()
{
    foreach (GameObject mn in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Moving Object"))
    {
        waypointsFollowers.Add(mn.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>());
    }
    
    StartCoroutine(SendObjectToMove());
}

private IEnumerator SendObjectToMove()
{
    foreach (WaypointsFollower follwer in waypointsFollowers)
    {
        // continue your code, but use follower instead of the other object
        // you are already storing these objects, so why not reuse them?
    }
}

private void UpdateSpeed(float speed)
{
    foreach (WaypointsFollower follwer in waypointsFollowers)
    {
        follower.speed = speed
    }
}
```

I am only using the `FindGameObjectsWithTag` once in `Start()` then reusing the list `waypointsFollowers` it is adding to. I added a function `UpdateSpeed` that will take a float as a parameter and update every object in the list.